# the usage of "less" verb in a context

Tags: word-choice

I was sitting with a friend of mine, and we were discussing a specific issue and he was very liberal. After having a cup of coffee, he started to be more conservative about the same issue. So, I told him "it seems that the coffee lesses your liberality" I feel that this sentence is an awkward, especially when using the word "lesses", isn't it? How to rephrase the sentence to more natural appearance?

Comment: I can't decide if I would more naturally use **lessens** or **reduces**. But I likely wouldn't use such a construction at all. I'd simply say "it seems that coffee makes you more conservative," just as you did when describing the question . . .

Answer (score 1):

## Is lesses a word?

I have only found 1 instance where it is a noun ([thefreedictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Lesses)) but the word is probably archaic.

**“Lesses” is not a word in the OED or Macmillan Dictionary.**

---

## I think you mean lessens...

I think you mean the word “lessens” which is a type of verb. Furthermore, the verb *seems* can be a **linking verb** and it is such in this case.

> It **seems** that the coffee lessens your liberality

**How can you tell?**

If you can replace “seems” with verb form of **to be** (am, is, are etc.) it is a linking verb. However the *that* is just placed awkwardly, but if we switch it to:

> “It is the coffee **that** lessens your liberality

or **that** can even be removed:

> It seems the coffee lessens your liberality

Now since, linking verbs do not denote action but rather connects the subject with nouns, “the coffee” describes the subject "it" or acts as a subject-compliment and so it needs an **action verb**, such as *lessens* and we can replace *lessens* with other action verbs:

> It seems that the coffee *X* your liberality.

*X* can be replaced with = *weakens*, *heightens*

Notice how they are 3rd person present verbs, because it is written in the 3rd person.

Answer (score 0):

"So, I told him "it seems that the coffee **[lessens](https://www.freethesaurus.com/lessen)** your liberality." works pretty well. Other synonyms of lessen , such as mitigates or reduces et. al. may work for you too.

Comment: Just a little side note; liberality and *liberalism* mean different things. Liberalism is best reserved for politics.